# Express/NodeJS - RESTful way of uploading images and filtering products

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I want to transform my application in REST convention and I don't know what is the correct form of uploading an image or applying filter for products.

About uploading image: on my client side user uploads an image, then I save it on my backend. Then I get back the image path from my backend (because I use a product preview and I need to see the image). And after when the users submits his product I just save the uploaded images path. So the image upload is not dependent on product upload, but it's strongly connected.

About my filtering: the filtering parameters and values are not static, these are always modifying data, so I used POST for this and I get the filter values from my request body as a JS object.

These are the calls from my client side:

```
export const uploadImage = (formData,config) => API.post('/product/uploadImage',formData,config)
export const getAllProducts = (querydata) => API.post('/product/getProducts',querydata)
```

My server routing:

```
router.post('/uploadImage', uploadImage)
router.post('/getProducts',getProducts)
```

My controllers:

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file")


export const uploadImage = (req, res) => {
     upload(req, res, err => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, err })
        }
        return res.json({ success: true, image: res.req.file.path, fileName: res.req.file.filename })
    })
};


export const getProducts= async (req) => {
  const findArgs={}
    req.body.filters.forEach((categoryObject) => {
        let objectKey=Object.keys(categoryObject)[0]
        findArgs[objectKey]={$in:categoryObject[objectKey]}
    })

 ...
```

How can I modify this to have a RESTful structure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no specific REST specification, your methods should be generally defined in this way:

- `GET: /products`
  Get all products (you can also define a filter using query parameters eg: `GET: /products?category=book&author=hawkins`)
- `POST: /products` - Create a new product
- `DELETE: /products/:id` - Delete a product
- `PATCH: /products/:id` - Edit a product
- `POST: /products/:id/image` - Add an image to the product
- `GET: /products/:id` - Fetch a single product

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this will not work in my case:  ```POST: /products/:id/image```, images are added before a product is created, ```GET: /products?category=book&author=hawkins```, these categories are always modifying so I will not know how to refer for the params, because these are fully dynamic and it can also happen that I will have 10+ parameters with values.

Comment: In this case, you can always add a form-data field on the `POST: /products` endpoint to add the image, when you create the product. 

About the categories, you can even define more versatile filters such as key/value pairs e.g.: `GET: /products?filter=<key>,<value>`